# print the matched one at a sequence after testing with if statements skip the one that don't match

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

```
if np.any( pts1 == "to_be_verb") or np.any( pts1 == "wh_type"):
 if np.any( pts2 == "wh_type") or np.any( pts3 == "interrogation"):
```

here, in the result i want to print the matched one from each statement at a sequence and in case of not matching any individual one it will print nothing there and print the next if statement's one if matched.

if the result come like this:

```
pts1 == to_be_verb
pts2 == 
pts3 == interrogation
```

then it will grab and print the pts1+pts3

but if the result come like this:

```
pts1 == to_do_verb
pts2 == wh_type
pts3 == interrogation
```

then it will grab and print the pts1+pts2+pts3

and if the result come like this:

```
pts1 == 
pts2 == 
pts3 == interrogation
```

then it will grab and print the pts3

any idea, any help, please?

Comment: @ tripleee okay, but have any idea to solve the problem for now anyway dear ?

Comment: I don't understand the question, and have voted to close it as unclear. If you can [edit] it to clarify it, it seems to amount to refactoring the `if` statements. I'm guessing `np.any` is a [tag:numpy] function so you should probably add that tag.